# Problemas com carregamento de .js e .css em arquivos externos .php

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, ajax

Tenho uma aplicação que esta apresentando um problema que nunca havia acontecido antes, recentemente comecei a utilizar JavaScript para carregamento de conteúdo sem refresh utilizando ajax, só que isso ocasionou em um problema. Todo arquivo externo .php que é chamado eque precisa do jquery.js acabada não funcionando, a única forma que funciona é se eu chamar novamente o jquery.js no arquivo externo .php, só que isso acaba fazendo com que o jquery.js que o menu utiliza, chamado na index,  pare de funcionar, tornando o menu sem ação e travando a barra de rolagem. O que eu poderia fazer para que isso não aconteça e para que eu não que chamar o jquery.js toda vez que ele for necessário em um arquivo externo? Vou deixar um exemplo a baixo do fluxo de minha aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para explicar melhor:

O arquivo `Index.php` possui a linha abaixo

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

e o `detalhes.php` para que funcione as funções do JQuery precisa da mesma linha acima.

Comment: Provavelmente você está usando `$("element").click( ... )`, caso esteja, substitua por `$("element_parent").on("click", "element", function() { ... })`

Comment: Não, estou usando $(document).ready(function(){}).

Comment: Adicione como você utiliza o AJAX na sua pergunta

Comment: Ajax é um dos casos, isso ocorre com outras importações de js

Comment: @Rafa_Dev e como você está atribuindo os eventos (de *click*, *change* etc) aos elementos?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr esta é uma da funções que preciso colocar a chamada do js em todas as paginas que a utilizo -> $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#nomeproduto").typeahead({
    source: function (query, resultado) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "auxiliares/z-aux_busca_produto.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {query: query},
        success: function (data) {
          resultado($.map(data, function (item) {
            return item;
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

Comment: Parta do princípio de que uma requisição Ajax deve retornar basicamente um HTML (no seu caso, um JSON). O jQuery é JavaScript que só deve ser executado no navegador. Se você estiver usando jQuery na página PHP requisitada pelo Ajax, é um erro, porque a página PHP não está sendo executada no navegador, e sim no servidor, ou seja, se você coloca a biblioteca jQuery na página PHP requisitada, o jQuery não terá nenhum efeito lá, ele apenas será retornado para a página que chamou o Ajax.

Comment: resumindo, qualquer código JavaScript (como jQuery) que você colocar na página PHP requisitada, será executado não lá, mas no retorno do Ajax se você inserir o response em algum lugar da página que fez a requisição.